# Beautiful Soup does not find tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to search different tags (and their contents) in a html file (see below). The only tag I can find is the  tag (td3). All other tags I tried for the html code below results in an empty result. The html string is taken from a html file with much more data, but it behave the same way with the original html file. I'm using python 3.6 (anaconda) on a windows OS. I would be very happy for comments on that problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SRPI>
<Measurement>
<Table1 corrected="no"><!--Spectrum of the sample measurement-->
<NumberOfBins>991</NumberOfBins>
<SampleFreq units="Hz">5.0000000000000000e+006</SampleFreq>
<SpecBins units="A m^2">
<data>
<complex real="-1.2725117264933506e-006" imag="-2.3275671788139798e-007"/>
<complex real="6.8157835062885686e-013" imag="4.5930196651468919e-013"/>
<complex real="-6.4585657824646980e-012" imag="4.7539847709910694e-012"/>
<complex real="-9.4822601663528955e-013" imag="3.6107393400439346e-012"/>
<complex real="-6.9440051626638662e-012" imag="1.3120684697626131e-011"/>
</data></SpecBins>
<Slope units="1">-1.3228643789347363e+000</Slope>
<SpecDen units="A^2 m^4"><SpecDen300>4.0594355476938474e-013</SpecDen300>        
<SpecDen1000>3.3641372153210487e-017</SpecDen1000></SpecDen>
<NoiseDen units="A^2 m^4"><NoiseDen1000>6.6288807841262445e-025
</NoiseDen1000><NoiseDen2500>2.3871617742749738e-020</NoiseDen2500>  
</NoiseDen>
</Table1>
<Table1 corrected="yes"><!--Spectrum correction file-->
<NumberOfBins>991</NumberOfBins>
<SampleFreq units="Hz">5.0000000000000000e+006</SampleFreq><SpecBins  
units="A m^2">
<data>
<complex real="-6.1985809140785431e-010" imag="-1.1337902190172509e-010"/>
<complex real="2.6627789950911842e-012" imag="1.5055359912912377e-012"/>
<complex real="-3.1088631626418299e-012" imag="8.2499406092681002e-012"/>
<complex real="-3.7649152780239330e-012" imag="1.2053978204849702e-011"/>
<complex real="5.1454481954799239e-012" imag="1.7627441490145078e-011"/>
</data></SpecBins>
<Slope units="1">-1.3228179094677259e+000</Slope><SpecDen units="A^2 
m^4"><SpecDen300>4.0577224679625485e-013</SpecDen300>
<SpecDen1000>3.3638569547225415e-017</SpecDen1000></SpecDen><NoiseDen 
units="A^2 m^4"><NoiseDen1000>1.1074994155863766e-024</NoiseDen1000>
<NoiseDen2500>2.3085849697684034e-003</NoiseDen2500></NoiseDen>
</Table1>
<Table2><TARawDataSize>1980</TARawDataSize>
<TARawData>
<data>1.0392482964229389e-001</data>
<data>7.4384450858019771e-002</data>
<data>4.7129165401792232e-002</data>
<data>2.2414031730721266e-002</data>
<data>1.6249028219891167e-004</data>
<data>-2.0196675622799122e-002</data>
<data>-3.9955558403595014e-002</data>
</TARawData><MeasurementTime units="ms">10000</MeasurementTime>
<FieldStrength units="microTesla">1.0000000000000000e+004</FieldStrength>   
<DateMeasurement>20180522_111708</DateMeasurement>
</Table2>
<Table3><SoftwareVersion> %version: 0.7 % </SoftwareVersion>  
<FormatVersion>1.0</FormatVersion>
<HardwareID>VSM Spectrometer 2.1</HardwareID>
<MeasurementType>1</MeasurementType>  
<CorrectionFile>C:\correct.txt</SampleID></Table3>
<Table4>
<DateCalib>20110707_091006</DateCalib>  
<CalibTransmit>3.1499999999999999e+000</CalibTransmit>
<CalibReceive>
<data>
<complex real="1.3152490026529447e-005" imag="2.4057384673215519e-006"/>
<complex real="5.9217813163382713e-006" imag="7.4460089732908548e-006"/>
<complex real="2.8667597217130651e-006" imag="6.6739599860582135e-006"/>
<complex real="1.4393526301410223e-006" imag="5.6813939622965668e-006"/>
<complex real="6.6555358632601569e-007" imag="4.8684922052003432e-006"/>
<complex real="2.0061980917706046e-007" imag="4.2296081097640261e-006"/>
</data></CalibReceive><RefCoilID>Probe 1E</RefCoilID>
</Table4>
</Measurement></SRPI>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(string,"lxml")
td1=soup.findAll('NumberOfBins')
print(td1)
td2=soup.findAll('SampleFreq')
print(td2)
td3=soup.findAll('data')
print(td3)
```

Comment: The first obvious problem is that, contrary to what your question says this is not HTML. And you’re using 'lxml' as your parser, which means LXML in HTML mode, not in XML mode. Read the docs on how to pick the right parser.

Comment: That might even be your _only_ problem. HTML and XML have different rules for how they handle case, and you happen to be successfully matching an all-lowercase tag but failing to match two mixed-case tags…

Comment: The second obvious problem is that you’re using `findAll`, which is a deprecated method from BS3. It does happen to do the same thing as `find_all`, so it should work here… but if you’re copying and pasting from sample code that ancient without realizing that it’s ancient, who knows what else might be wrong?

Comment: The parser converts tags into lowercase: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=tag#other-parser-problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup standardises the parse tree on input and converts tags to **lower-case**

```
>>> soup.findAll('numberofbins')
[<numberofbins>991</numberofbins>, <numberofbins>991</numberofbins>]
>>> 
>>> soup.findAll('samplefreq')
[<samplefreq units="Hz">5.0000000000000000e+006</samplefreq>, <samplefreq units="Hz">5.0000000000000000e+006</samplefreq>]
>>>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. Can you please accept the answer

Comment: The HTML parser converts tags to lowercase. But the OP shouldn’t be using the HTML parser with XML data in the first place, so this is the wrong fix. M

Comment: What would be the right fix from your point of view. Thank you for your comments

Comment: I believe, since you're using XML, you'd use lxml-xml to specify xml parsing. From the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser